# KVM image failed to start with virsh, permission denied

Tags: ubuntu, linux-kvm

My host OS is Ubuntu Server 11.04 (natty)

After following the instructions detailed by Ubuntu's [help](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KVM), I created one KVM image using

```
sudo ubuntu-vm-builder kvm hardy --libvirt qemu:///system
```

The image file was created as

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 438M 2011-06-17 14:39 ubuntu-kvm/tmpK9hbU5.qcow2
```

The I can list it with virsh by 
sudo virsh -c qemu:///system "list --all"

```
Id   Name                 State
----------------------------------
  - ubuntu               shut off
```

Buth when I call

```
sudo virsh -c qemu:///system "start ubuntu"
```

The error was thrown up:

```
error: Failed to start domain ubuntu
error: internal error process exited while connecting to monitor: kvm: -drive file=/home/myuser/vmopt/ubuntu-kvm/tmpK9hbU5.qcow2,if=none,id=drive-ide0-0-0,format=qcow2: could not open disk image /home/myuser/vmopt/ubuntu-kvm/tmpK9hbU5.qcow2: Permission denied
```

The user "myuser" had been added to group libvirt.

I've gone so far as to chmod the image file as well its directory to 777, but the error is still there.

Answer (score 10):

KVM images are restricted by selinux.  Putting them in /var/lib/libvirt/images should suffice.

http://libvirt.org/drvqemu.html#securityselinux goes into more detail.

Comment: Man!! This worked for me. Thanks a lot man. Apparently the $HOME directory of your account is protected wich is where virsh likes to install things at by default. After I installed my vms, I ran mv $HOME/vmfolder /var/lib/libvirt/images. Then I ran virsh edit vmname and changed the image file's location accordingly.

Comment: I also had to change the owner of one of my vms. It belonged to root which led to an access denied. sudo chown -R libvirt-qemu:kvm dbos/ubuntu-kvm/. You can run ls -l on/your/vm/dir/and/its/subdirs/ to check permissions at each level. Ensure none of them belong to the root group and user.

Comment: I've found that the easiest and safest way to create your vm's is to make sure you cd to this directory /var/lib/libvirt/images and run your install from there. That way you won't have to worry about the folder level permissions. They'll just default to the current user as opposed to root.

Answer (score 6):

a easy solution would be to edit the /etc/libvirt/qemu.conf file and uncommenting the following lines:

```
User = "root"
group = "root"
```

Don't forget to restart libvirtd

Comment: That might let you run it, but what are the security implications?

Comment: Probably better to add yourself to the `kvm` group, adjust the image file permissions accordingly, and set `user="<yourname>"` in `qemu.conf`.

Answer (score 2):

In Arch Linux:

```
sudo usermod -a -G kvm username
```

set permissions for QEMU processes in `/etc/libvirt/qemu.conf`

```
user = "username"
group = "kvm"
```

to refresh group membership in the same terminal:

```
su - username
```

Add an alias to your `~/.bashrc`

```
alias virsh='EDITOR=nano sudo virsh && cd /etc/libvirt/qemu'
```

finally

```
source ~/.bashrc
virsh
list --all
start mydomain
```

Answer (score 2):

Running QEMU with root privileges is not advised, as from version 6.0.0 it would not strip the Linux capabilities.

In my case it was AppArmor. I wanted to add an SSDT file for a battery to the VM. There are some folders which AppArmor allows access to, and others (like `/home/something`) are just not allowed. `/var/lib/libvirt/images/` is one of the allowed folders. Although i placed my file there, it was still not allowed by AppArmor policy (as can be seen with `sudo cat /var/log/kern.log | grep -C 10 apparmor | grep -C 10 qemu`). What worked was adding `/var/lib/libvirt/images/SSDT1.dat rk` in `/etc/apparmor.d/libvirt/TEMPLATE.qemu` like this:

```
#
# This profile is for the domain whose UUID matches this file.
#

#include <tunables/global>

profile LIBVIRT_TEMPLATE flags=(attach_disconnected) {
  #include <abstractions/libvirt-qemu>
  /var/lib/libvirt/images/SSDT1.dat rk,
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seem this permission-error can also be related to corrupted qcow2  overlay/snapshots!

In had this setup:

`Baseimage` > `Overlay1` > `Overlay2`

The overlays was created with cmd `virsh snapshot-create ...` and `Overlay1` was newer used (VM not started) before creating `Overlay2` (created for testing).

Not a very likely IRL use case, but nonetheless it got this error and it was driving me nuts until I realized if was related to the overlay chain and not file-system access permissions.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar "permission denied" error while trying to boot Windows 10 from a physical SSD using KVM/QEMU/virt-manager on Debian 10. I was able to solve the issue, without giving QEMU root privileges (not recommended as noted in other answers), by using [Access Control Lists](https://wiki.debian.org/Permissions) (ACL) to change the permissions only for the file that QEMU actullly needed (in my case the `/dev/disk/by-id/<disk-id>` handle).

To see current user or group permissions for a file, use `getfacl <file>`.

I gave the `libvirt` and `libvirt-qemu` groups read-write permission on the SSD using `setfacl <file>`, and the VM was able to boot right away:

```bsh
sudo setfacl --modify group:libvirt:rw- /dev/disk/by-id/<disk-id>
sudo setfacl --modify group:libvirt-qemu:rw- /dev/disk/by-id/<disk-id>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this was already solved or not, but it worked for me when I disabled **SELinux** in all Red Hat distributions (Centos, Fedora ...):

```
setenforce Permissive
```

If someone need permanent change :  we must update `/etc/sysconfig/selinux`
and set `**SELINUX=permissive**`

After that restarting the VM would be possible.